# Module dependencies in IntelliJ while importing an Eclipse-project

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, intellij-idea

I'm working in a project where the main IDE is Eclipse. The Eclipse workspace is made up of several projects that depend on each other in a chain like so:

- lib-project with all external dep
- endencies jar-files and stuff
- ProjectA depends on lib-project
- ProjectB depends on project A
- ProjectC depends on project B
- etc

I think (someone correct me if I'm wrong) that modules In Eclipse inherit their dependencies, so that in the case above C also can use stuff defined in A and the lib-project.

When importing the Eclipse project into IntelliJ all the dependencies got set up ok, but I had to add dependencies C->A, C-> lib-project by hand. Am I doing something wrong or is this just the way it's supposed to work?

I'm using IntelliJ 9.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think (someone correct me if I'm wrong) that modules In Eclipse inherit their dependencies, so that in the case above C also can use stuff defined in A and the lib-project.

I'm afraid it's not correct. Eclipse requires explicit dependencies as well. It's achieved via Export checkbox for the dependency in IDEA Module Dependencies settings.

If you have a counter example of the Eclipse project which works in the way you've described and doesn't work that way in IDEA, please send it to JetBrains Support.